# i want to scrape this part

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape each panel in the screenshot but i didn't get the right xpath to scrape those parts .Any one can help me please.

[image]

https://www.seloger.com/annonces/achat/appartement/paris-15eme-75/saint-lambert/142632059.htm?cp=75&idtt=2,5&idtypebien=2,1&LISTING-LISTpg=2&naturebien=1,2,4&tri=initial&

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This data is taken from additional request to `https://www.seloger.com/detail,json,caracteristique_bien.json?idannonce=142632059`. There you will get json with whole information.

UPD:

```
url_id = re.search(r'/(\d+)\.htm', response.url).group(1)
details_url = 'https://www.seloger.com/detail,json,caracteristique_bien.json?idannonce={}'
# make request to url
yield Request(details_url.format(url_id))
```

Comment: and how can i get it

Comment: where can i find this json and get the information inside?

Comment: By this url. Did you make request to it?

Comment: yeah but i don't know how can i get the url for each ad because i'm gonna scrape many ads so i will be in need for an xpath that can guide me to this url

Comment: You just need id from your main url. Apply it to details link and parse result. That's it. I've updated answer with code.